# DB2 contention issues

Tags: database, stored-procedures, db2, cobol, mainframe

We are experiencing serious performance degrades and sometimes outages due to DB2 contention issues.

Covol DB2 batch program is having contentions with distributed threads from Stored procedures causing to slow down the application and leading to outages.

Any help on how to eliminate these contentions?

Commits are already there. The contentions are only from distributed threads.

Comment: This is a job for your developers and your DBA. You will only solve this problem by working with your team.  Understand what changed (if this is a new problem). In general you solve locking problems by understanding the details of what is happening, and finding ways to work around, to optimize, to fix access-plans, to adjust code, and many others.  You cannot do this in a single questions for stackoverflow.  Involve your team!

Comment: You’d better ask this type of questions in [here](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datamanagement/communities/community-home?CommunityKey=621c2a2a-01f9-4b57-992f-36ed7432e3bb). 
And, for sure, you’ll need to provide more information that you do in this question. Be prepared to get some longs and a further description. 
Also, it is COBOL. For your searches.

Comment: One of the things we did was to eliminate any complex SQL.  We only used simple COBOL static SELECTS and CURSORS.  No GROUP.  No HAVING.  No SELECT within a SELECT.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc if you do that you make the complex stuff "Stage 3"  I.e. in your application code - which is likely to be less effficient. But I see what (I hope) you're getting at: Simplify the problem and work on that and then add the complexity back in.

Comment: Less efficient for your particular program.  However, better throughput for all programs.

Answer (score 2):

Both @mao and @Pasamonte are correct in their comments.

Someone, possibly one of your DBAs, is going to be examining system logs to determine which SQL is in contention and the EXPLAIN output of that SQL.

The JESMSGLG of the DB2 STC where the contention is occurring may have messages that help.  Any monitoring tools you have (Omegamon, etc.) can help.

There is a plethora of things to look at, far beyond what can be done within the scope of an answer on SO.  Are there LOCK TABLE statements?  How are the packages bound?  Is there an index missing?